# Add a colorbar and fill polygons based on value

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am working with Basemap and a shapefile to create polygons that overlay my basemap. That's all working well and good but now I want to fill in the polygons with varying shades of the color green based on a value in a list between 1 and 100.

I have a sorted list of tuples that looks like this:

```
kk = Counter(table["county"]).items()
## sort based on the second item in the tuple
kk = sorted(kk, key=lambda x: x[1])

kk

[('EL DORADO', 1),
 ('SAN FRANCISCO', 1),
 ('SACRAMENTO', 2),
 ('SAN MATEO', 3),
 ('SHASTA', 3),
 ('ALAMEDA', 5),
 ('CONTRA COSTA', 5),
 ('HUMBOLDT', 6),
 ('PLUMAS', 6),
 ('SOLANO', 9),
 ('LOS ANGELES', 10),
 ('SAN BENITO', 18)...]
```

I separate the tuples and access their values separately using this function:

```
def separateSortedValues(arg):
    s_x = []
    s_y = []

    for x in kk:
        s_x.append(x[0])
        s_y.append(x[1])

    return([s_x, s_y])
```

Here is my code where I iterate through a shapefile looking for polygons that have the county name I am looking for. If that is true they are added to a list named `patches`. `patches` is then passed to a `PatchCollection` where I have some control over the colors that are being assigned.

```
def fill_counties(table_data):

    patches = []

    counties = table_data[0]

    for info, shape in zip(map.counties_info, map.counties):
        if info["NAME"] in counties:
            patches.append(Polygon(np.array(shape), True))

    filled_polygons = PatchCollection(patches, facecolor="green", edgecolor="gray", linewidths=.5, zorder=2)    
    return(ax.add_collection(filled_polygons))

fill_counties(separateSortedValues(kk))
```

I want to be able to make each Polygon a varying color of green based on the `table[1]` value associated with the county because I don't think coloring the entire PatchCollection `facevalue` one color is the right way to go.

Comment: replace `facecolor` with `array=your_values` and `cmap="Greens".

Comment: so something like `facecolor = array'?

Comment: No, rather like I said in the above comment.

Comment: `patches, array=my_values, cmap="greens"` like that?